# Rocket Universe basic suppressing output to screen

Tags: universe

Via universe basic how do I suppress output to the screen, vaguely remember from PICK R83 days it's an execute statement? Please note don't want to output to any other device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In programs it is common to use

```
HUSH ON
;*Code with output you want to suppress goes here
HUSH OFF
```

The 'P' business you mentioned also works but it is also the P)age command in the editor. That has only bitten me about once a week for past decade.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing came up with the following basic solution:

```
EXECUTE 'P'    ;* Toggle screen display off
....
EXECUTE 'P'    ;* Toggle screen display on
```

Not sure if echo on/off has the same desired effect, and maybe a pick specific flavor?